# How to show only first and last labels in CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

[image]

I need to show first and last labels only in CanvasJS. It's always showing all the labels but my requirement is to show only first and last. Is there any way out to do so?

Comment: Why not post your solution when you say it's better as the ones posted?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [axisY labelFormatter](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/label-formatter/) to do so.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 title: {
  text: "Chart showing only First and Last Axis Labels",
 },
 axisY: {
  tickColor: "transparent",
  labelFormatter: function(e){
   if(e.chart.axisY[0].minimum === e.value || e.chart.axisY[0].maximum === e.value)
    return e.value;
   return "";
  }
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 10, y: 71 },
   { x: 20, y: 55 },
   { x: 30, y: 50 },
   { x: 40, y: 65 },
   { x: 50, y: 95 },
   { x: 60, y: 68 },
   { x: 70, y: 28 },
   { x: 80, y: 34 },
   { x: 90, y: 14 }
  ]
 }]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: thnx for the your time but i hav efound another way to it .  :)

Comment: Can you share please how you did it @mfs

Answer (score 1):

You can also try hiding all axis-labels and add stripLines at the minimum and maximum.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
title: {
 text: "Chart showing only First and Last Axis Labels",
},
axisX: {
 valueFormatString: "####"
},
axisY:[{
 tickColor: "transparent",
 labelFontColor: "transparent"
}],
axisY2:[{
 tickColor: "transparent",
 labelFontColor: "transparent"
}],
data: [
{
 type: "column",
 showInLegend: true,
 name: "Axis Y-1",
 xValueFormatString: "####",
 dataPoints: [
  { x: 2006, y: 6 },
  { x: 2007, y: 2 },
  { x: 2008, y: 5 },
  { x: 2009, y: 7 },
  { x: 2010, y: 1 },
  { x: 2011, y: 5 },
  { x: 2012, y: 5 },
  { x: 2013, y: 2 },
  { x: 2014, y: 2 }
 ]
},
{
 type: "column",
 showInLegend: true,                  
 axisYType: "secondary",
 //axisYIndex: 0, //Defaults to Zero
 name: "Axis Y2-1",
 xValueFormatString: "####",
 dataPoints: [
  { x: 2006, y: 12 },
  { x: 2007, y: 20 },
  { x: 2008, y: 28 },
  { x: 2009, y: 34 },
  { x: 2010, y: 24 },
  { x: 2011, y: 45 },
  { x: 2012, y: 15 },
  { x: 2013, y: 34 },
  { x: 2014, y: 22 }
 ]
}     
]
});

chart.render();
addStripLine(chart);

function addStripLine(chart){
for(var i = 0; i < chart.axisY.length; i++){
 min = chart.axisY[i].get("minimum");      
 max = chart.axisY[i].get("maximum");
 chart.axisY[i].addTo("stripLines", {value: min, color: "black", label: min, labelFontColor: "black", labelBackgroundColor: "transparent", labelPlacement: "outside"});
 chart.axisY[i].addTo("stripLines", {value: max, color: "black", label: max, labelFontColor: "black", labelBackgroundColor: "transparent", labelPlacement: "outside"});
}
for(var i = 0; i < chart.axisY2.length; i++){
 min = chart.axisY2[i].get("minimum");
 max = chart.axisY2[i].get("maximum");
 chart.axisY2[i].addTo("stripLines", {value: min, color: "black", label: min, labelFontColor: "black", labelBackgroundColor: "transparent", labelPlacement: "outside"});
 chart.axisY2[i].addTo("stripLines", {value: max, color: "black", label: max, labelFontColor: "black", labelBackgroundColor: "transparent", labelPlacement: "outside"});
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the your time but i have found another way to it :)