# How to show only the first and last label pick in C3.js?

Tags: c3.js

I have a time series C3.js chart, but I haven't found a way to only show the first and last X label tick. I saw a solution in Canvas.js but not sure how to apply the same method in C3.js.
[How to show only first and last labels in CanvasJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699685/how-to-show-only-first-and-last-labels-in-canvasjs)
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'count' setting for the x axis to 2 in your chart configuration.

https://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_count.html (change it to 2 in here to see it at work)